# passing the output from a js file to another php file

Tags: php, javascript

I have an output from a javascript file in the format

and the js files look like

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php",
data: { name: "term", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
  });
```

I want to output these values in a separate excel file.. So Ive used php and wrote a script in to another file

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv'); 
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Type', 'Entity Name', 'Link'));
fputcsv($output, results);
?>
```

and included the javascript file inside the header part of php file.. bt I dont get the "result" output generated by the js file. 
How can I pass the result from js file to php file?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to pass data from js to php is via POST or GET requests.

This is an old school tutorial about it: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

The "new" and easy way is via ajax with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

JS:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
```

In "msg" you receive what you return from your php script.

Comment: so I can pass the array results to php file using jquery?

Comment: you can pass whatever you want via GET or POST parameters to php using jquery

Comment: Ive edited the code part in question as I did..bt its nt wrking

Comment: you have to include the latest version of jquery also: http://jquery.com/download/ and you need 2 separate files: one for js and parsing the response, and one for your php script

Comment: and the php error is also getting printed inside excel file like undefined index